# Best practice - transfer data between web services using esb

Tags: esb

I would like to ask you about best practise in sending data (POST/GET variable) between two web services, where between them is ESB:

**WEB_SERVICE1   <----------->   ESB   <---------->   WEB_SERVICE2**

Should I create another webservice in ESB, which will transfer data between **WEB_SERVICE1** and **WEB_SERVICE2**?

Answer (score 5):

Translations within the ESB is how you should transfer data from one web service to another.

You should leverage the ESB to do the communication between the two.

You generally use translators/mappers provided by the ESB framework to facilitate the translation/formats of data coming in and out.

1. Web Service 1 pushes message to ESB
2. ESB reads post/get data, formats data to meet Web Service 2 demands
3. ESB redirects/post to Web Service 2

**Edit**

You might want to give us some more info on how you are planing on using these.  Are you just trying to call one service from another ?  Or are you trying to do something more

If you just want to not worry about p2p, then ideally you would have webservice 1 push a message to the message bus, the message bus would pick it up and, translate it, and deliver it to web service 2 (or any other subscribers).

[Take a look a message endpoints in the Fuse Integration Patterns document](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.4.1/camel_eip/camel_eip.pdf)

Comment: Okay, but if i wanna push some data to ESB, the ESB shoud have some web service, which will be able to receive request from WEB_SERVICE1?

Comment: I want to create message bus, which will be able to do something more with the data. But now i'm wondering if i want to send some data from one web service to another throw ESB, do i have to create another web service, which will be running under FUSE ESB or FUSE ESB have some components which i can use to my work. I found camel http component, which can send my data to web service, but at first i dont know how i can send data to ESB, thats why i'm asking if i need webservice, or i can use ready component